# MySQL query to aggregate the number of versions created over previous 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores versions of Products (`product_versions`). These product versions
can have a set of statuses (`active`, `draft`, `archived`) and I need get a result set of the  aggregate of these statuses for each day (historically) so that a graph can be generated.

While I know that I can use application code (PHP) or database triggers to build and maintain an aggregate table, I am hoping to solve this in a query (partly because I want it to be elegant, and partly because I'm curious about how to do it). If I can achieve this, I can then cache the result or similar.

So far I am able to get the result for a single status like this:

```sql
SELECT
    pv.created_at_date,
    (
        SELECT CONCATcount(*)
        FROM `product_versions` p
        JOIN (
            SELECT product_id, MAX(id) AS latest_version
            FROM product_versions
            GROUP BY product_id
        ) grouped_versions ON p.product_id = grouped_versions.product_id AND p.id = grouped_versions.latest_version
        WHERE created_at_date = pv.created_at_date
        AND status = 'draft'
        ORDER BY id ASC
    ) as draft_status_count_subquery,
FROM product_versions pv
WHERE created_at_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)
GROUP BY pv.created_at_date
ORDER BY pv.created_at_date desc
```

Result:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| created_at_date | draft_status_count_subquery |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| 2013-09-09      |                           0 |
| 2013-09-06      |                          26 |
| 2013-09-05      |                          40 |
| 2013-09-04      |                          46 |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+
```

It's important to note that I need to be able to determine the status of the latest version for each day (using the grouped_versions sub-query) in order to return correct aggregates.

All my other attempts to join in additional statuses have not worked (besides the obvious which is to add additional sub-queries (status_count_subquery 1 .. n) for each status which I'm reluctant to do because the performance is already quite slow with only 1 sub-query).

Thus, I ask the world out there, is there a better way to achieve this result (or similar)?

**Test data**

Here is some sample data to re-create the scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_versions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `product_versions` (`id`, `product_id`, `created_at_date`, `title`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2013-09-06', 'Foo Product', 'draft'),
    (2, 1, '2013-09-06', 'Foo Product', 'active'),
    (3, 2, '2013-09-06', 'Bar Product', 'draft'),
    (4, 1, '2013-09-07', 'Foo Product', 'archived'),
    (5, 2, '2013-09-07', 'Bar Product', 'active'),
    (6, 3, '2013-09-07', 'Baz Product', 'draft'),
    (7, 4, '2013-09-07', 'Fiz Product', 'draft');
```

**Hoping for an output like this**

```
+-----------------+-------+--------+----------+
| created_at_date | draft | active | archived |
+-----------------+-------+--------+----------+
| 2013-09-07      |     2 |      1 |        1 |
| 2013-09-06      |     1 |      1 |        0 |
+-----------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data? On the surface it seems like you'd be better off using a conditional sum to get results for each status in one pass.

Comment: I've added some sample data. A conditional sum *sounds* like something that suits the problem although I've never used that technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed it (yay!) thanks to @Goat CO's suggestion:

```
SELECT
    p.created_at_date,
    SUM(status = 'draft') as draft,
    SUM(status = 'active') as active,
    SUM(status = 'archived') as archived
FROM `product_versions` p
JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, MAX(id) AS latest_version
    FROM product_versions
    GROUP BY created_at_date, product_id
) grouped_versions ON p.product_id = grouped_versions.product_id AND p.id = grouped_versions.latest_version
GROUP BY created_at_date
ORDER BY created_at_date DESC
```

Result

```
+-----------------+-------+--------+----------+
| created_at_date | draft | active | archived |
+-----------------+-------+--------+----------+
| 2013-09-07      |     2 |      1 |        1 |
| 2013-09-06      |     1 |      1 |        0 |
+-----------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Let me know if there is any other solutions worth looking at or if this solution has an error in it.